# How to search for a string in the list when the button is pressed in swt

Tags: java, swt, e4, listeners

I have created a tabfolder and created some tabs and in the tabs i have a composite which contains a list.So i have a textbox so when the string is typed in the textbox and find button is pressed  the list shoul be displayed containg the string so how can this be done.

The code to create textbox and find button is as follows

```
public void postConstruct (Composite parentComposite) {
        parentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        Composite topComposite = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        topComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        topComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

        Composite bottomComposite = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        GridData bottomCompositeGD = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BOTTOM, true, false);
        bottomCompositeGD.heightHint = 100;
        bottomComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        bottomComposite.setLayoutData(bottomCompositeGD);

        Composite topLeftComposite = new Composite(topComposite, SWT.NONE);
        topLeftComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        topLeftComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, false, true));

        Composite topRightComposite = new Composite(topComposite, SWT.NONE);
        topRightComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        topRightComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

                Composite findTCComposite = new Composite(topRightComposite, SWT.NONE);
        findTCComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
        findTCComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false));

        txtFindTC = new Text(findTCComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.SINGLE);
        txtFindTC.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false));


Button btnFindTC = new Button(findTCComposite, SWT.NONE);
        btnFindTC.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, GridData.BEGINNING, false, false));
        btnFindTC.setText("Find TC");

TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(topRightComposite, SWT.NONE);
        tabFolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

        TabItem itemBasicTC = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        itemBasicTC.setText("Basic TCs");

        createListViewBasicTc(tabFolder,itemBasicTC);


}



the the tab is created is below
private void createListViewBasicTc(Composite composite,TabItem itemBasicTC){
        final List list = new List(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        itemBasicTC.setControl(list);

        creatingDragSource(list);
        //final java.util.List<String> listSort = new ArrayList<String>();
        //for(int i = 1; i <=10 ; i++)
            list.add("TestCase          
            list.add("Test_)");
            list.add("something");


    }
```

so now when the user types "some"  in textbox and press find button in the tab it should display in the tab only "something".So how can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 button.addListener (SWT.Selection,  new Listener()
{


    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        //This depends on your search criteria
        String search = "A";
        Boolean  found = false;
        for (String str : list) {
            if (str.trim().contains(search)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```